# Spring Exception Handling (getting reason from message resource)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-aspects

How can set reason from message.properties in  @ResponseStatus?

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "**i want to get this from message resource**")
public class CreateOrderException extends RuntimeException{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using ExceptionHandlerAdvice instead of annotating the exception class. You can then intercept your CreateOrderException and shape your response according your needs.

a code snippet would be:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(CreateOrderException.class)
    public void handleException(CreateOrderException exception, HttpServlerResponse response){
         String msg = gettingMessageFromYourException(exception);
         response.sendError(400, msg);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set your project parameter to send the message with error response:
**server.error.include-message**
by default it is hidden.

Alternatively you may change return type of handleException to ResponseEntity and then build it according needs:

```
....
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(yourCustomResponseBody);
```